# Help: Exercises about Types of Mobius transformations

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, mobius-transformation

I'm working on the following exercise of Jones, Gareth A., and David Singerman. Complex functions: an algebraic and geometric viewpoint. Cambridge university press, 1987.

### Exercise: 2D

Let $ S $ be a hyperbolic transformation with fixed-points $ p $ and $ q $. Let $ T $ be a Möbius transformation which maps $ p $ to $ q $. Prove that

- (i) $ STS^{-1}T^{-1} $ is hyperbolic,
- (ii) $ STST^{-1} $ is parabolic.

### my attempt for (i)

$STS^{-1}$ is the conjugate transformation of T by S, and this preserves the fixed points of S by Corollar 2.9.4 of the book. Thus, it's hyperbolic.

Then, I stopped as I don't know how to go about from here on.. any help is appreciated!